# How to set host address in python smtplib module?

Tags: python, email, host, anonymous

In linux environment, I want to connect to our company's mail server and send anonymous emails, it's host address in 10.18.93.128, and port is 25.

I don't know where to insert those information in code below, here gmail's server is used, but I want to use our mail server:

```
import smtplib  
fromaddr = 'anyemail@anyaddressx.com'  
toaddrs  = 'recipient_email@mycompany.com'  
msg = 'Hello'  


# Credentials (if needed)  
username = 'yyyyy'  
password = 'xxxxx'  

# The actual mail send  
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')  
server.starttls()  
server.login(username,password)  
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)  
server.quit()
```

My questions:

1. Where do I enter our mail server's host adress 10.18.93.128 and port
   above?
2. Is it possible to send email using a non-existing email account? It
   means I will not log in to an account, just send anonymous emails.

Thanks
Best Regards

Comment: Quick point in addition to Martijn's answer below. There's no guarantee that the e-mails you send will be anonymous so do not assume so. I'd be willing to bet that your company's configuration will mean that if you're logged onto your SMTP server from whatever box this is run from it'll be a mask for your personal e-mail address rather than a non-existent one.

Comment: "2. Is it possible to send email using a non-existing email account" - you can try, but it depends on the SMTP server setup if it will allow you to do so. Contact the mail server administrators, and ask them if this is possible. A most common approach for sending emails from a company email is to register an email `no-reply@domain.com`, and to use it for sending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace the `smtp.gmail.com:587` part:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('10.18.93.128:25')
```

You may have to omit the `starttls()` call depending on the configuration of your company email server.

It also depends on your email server whether or not it'll allow sending without logging in. The SMTP standard does not demand you log in, but company policy may.

Note that just because you have to log in to the mail server, you may still be able to send email using whatever `from` address you choose. Enforcing limitations on the from address is another policy decision a mail server can make.

Comment: Thanks, if it lets me send email without logging in, which part of the codes are not necessary above? Do I need `fromaddr` and `server.starttls()` parts?

Comment: You don't need `.starttls()`, that's part of the authentication process. You *do* need `fromaddr`.